# Manga where guy can manipulate skills and fuse them together to create new skills

Tags: story-identification, manga

This is what I do remember from the manga: in the beginning it turns out that our main character was summoned from another world but was either kicked out of the castle or was able to leave because they say he had no overpowered skill.

His skill actually turns out being able to manipulate skills and fuse them together to create new skills. He does this and sells the skill to then buy a slave that these spirits told him to buy because the spirits wanted him to save her.

After buying her, the person he sold the skill to then thought he might have more skills to sell him or a way to obtain those skills, so they go after our main character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it and this is the manga I was looking for. [*Isekai de Skill wo Kaitai shitara Cheat na Yome ga Zoushoku Shimashita: Gainen Kousa no Structure*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/108316/Isekai_de_Skill_wo_Kaitai_shitara_Cheat_na_Yome_ga_Zoushoku_Shimashita__Gainen_Kousa_no_Structure), aka *Being Able to Edit Skills in Another World, I Gained OP Waifus*.

> When an entire bus of people is summoned to another world, Souma Nagi doesn't go along with the idea of being a Hero like the rest. Thus he decides to leave the palace and start his life in another world with his new ability to restructure skills.

Comment: Alright thank you for the help and I am planning on reading the one that you originally thought the manga i said was

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it might be *[Isekai Shihai No Skill Taker: Zero Kara Hajimeru Dorei Harem](https://myanimelist.net/manga/101243/Isekai_Shihai_no_Skill_Taker__Zero_kara_Hajimeru_Dorei_Harem)*

[image: Front cover of Isekai Shihai No Skill Taker: Zero Kara Hajimeru Dorei Harem]

> Konoe Yuuto is a genius martial artist who is summoned to a different world where slave trading is legal. There, using his "Skill Taker" cheat ability, he steals the abilities of monsters he defeats, and starts building a slave harem while hoping to live a carefree life after retirement.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be it sadly. thank you for helping to find it though.

Comment: Ah, are there non-matching parts that you might be able to edit into your question?

Comment: I don't really remember to much more from the magna i just remember that he main point was that he could copy / manipulate skills to then create new skills from that